# JavaScript addEventListener click and keycode

Tags: javascript, dom-events

- Works with mouse click.

  - key code does not trigger video stop.
  - keycode after added  `focus()` works but it can cause some problems.

---

I want keycode and mouse click to work all the time. Independently of each other, it will click on the button when I press the "space" button and when I click the mouse, it will click on the button.

```js
let testKey = document.querySelector(".switch-btn");

["click", "keypress"].forEach(ev => {
    testKey.addEventListener(ev, function(e) {
        if(ev == "click") {
            console.log("click");
            if(!testKey.classList.contains("slide")) {
                testKey.classList.add("slide");

            } else {

            }

        }
        if(e.keyCode === 32) {
            console.log("click, space");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <button class="switch-btn">
      <span>
        Play
      </span>
      <span>
        pause
      </span>
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: the key events are fired on button, only if button is the active element. eg. clicking on it. you can also navigate with tab, or right click the button, for keyevents to be triggered on the button.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but the reason they key doesn't register initially is because the button isn't focused. You might try calling `testKey.focus()` to ensure it's initially focused.

Comment: for a generic play/pause space control, consider adding the keypress event handler to document.body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event is deprecated and no longer recommended (See [Document: keypress event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)). Instead you can use the `keydown` event.

If your intention is to handle the `click` and `keydown` events separately then you should check the `detail` property for the `click` event handler. If the button is clicked the property will have a value of `1`. (See [UIEvent.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) documentation)

Unless the user focuses on the button using the tab key, the `keydown` event is not going to fire your handler. Adding a handler at the container or document level can overcome this. In the code below I have added such a handler and called the `stopPropagation` method within the handler on the button to prevent the event bubbling up to the document level.

```js
let testKey = document.querySelector(".switch-btn");

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        console.log("document: space pressed");
        doTheClassListThing();
    }
});

["click", "keydown"].forEach(ev => {
    testKey.addEventListener(ev, function(e) {
        if(ev == "click" & e.detail == 1) {
            console.log("click");
            doTheClassListThing();
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 32) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log("Button: space keydown");
            doTheClassListThing();
        }
    });
});

function doTheClassListThing() {
    console.log('doTheClassListThing() executed');
    if(!testKey.classList.contains("slide")) {
        testKey.classList.add("slide");
    } else {
    }
}
```

```html
    <button class="switch-btn">
      <span>
        Play
      </span>
      <span>
        pause
      </span>
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: nice code, but the "space" button doesn't trigger video pause in my project. Prints the console log only. Mouse Click works.

Comment: That would be because the logic for handling the events does exactly that. By checking the `detail` property the `classList` is amended only when the button is clicked.

Comment: I've changed the code in the answer to handle the `classList` in another function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but the reason the key doesn't register initially is because the button isn't focused. You could try calling `testKey.focus()` to ensure it's initially focused.

I do not recommend this approach--forcing focus on the button could create accessibility issues and interfere with other element interactions, but here's a snippet just to demonstrate how focusing the button resolves the issue.

I agree with Terry's comment below, that attaching event handlers on body would be less fraught.

```js
let testKey = document.querySelector(".switch-btn");

testKey.focus();

["click", "keypress"].forEach(ev => {
    testKey.addEventListener(ev, function(e) {
        if(ev == "click") {
            console.log("click");
            if(!testKey.classList.contains("slide")) {
                testKey.classList.add("slide");

            } else {

            }

        }
        if(e.keyCode === 32) {
            console.log("click, space");
        }
        testKey.focus();
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="switch-btn">
      <span>
        Play
      </span>
      <span>
        pause
      </span>
      <span class="switch"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: I think a better solution will be to listen to the key press events on the document. That is because while forcing focus on the button works, it might take the focus away from another element unexpectedly and is bad UX.

Comment: @Terry can you give me a keyword or article to research

Comment: I agree, @Terry, and I considered saying as much but I guess I was thinking more about demonstrating how the unfocused button was the issue. I should've been clear about this being A Bad Idea™. Answer updated with clarification.